# Set document element's innerHTML to a long string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I'm using JQuery to dynamically set a div element. It has multiple lines that have very specific spacing, so this is my code:

```
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = "Developer:  A <br/> &emsp;&emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; B <br> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &nbsp; C <br> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; D";
```

As you can see this code looks horrible, is there any way to set the innerHTML line by line? For example,

```
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = "Developer:  A";     
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = "Developer:  B";
```

and have it show up the same way?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can span multiple lines:

```js
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = "Developer:  A <br/>" +
                                            "Developer:  B";
```

Or, you can do multiple assignments:

```js
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML  = "Developer:  A <br/>";
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += "Developer:  B"; // Note the += instead of just =
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the text in separate lines inside the body, use div to get the text in the separate lines as below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("<div/>").html("Developer A").appendTo($("body"));
  $("<div/>").html("Developer B").appendTo($("body"));
  $("<div/>").html("Developer C").appendTo($("body"));
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you want to **add** string you can use `+=`

```
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = "Developer:  A";     
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += "Developer:  B";
```